# Is it possible to extend an AFSP training request?

Tags: flight-training, tsa

My training request expires in a week or so. Is it possible to extend it or do I have to submit a new one if I'm running out of time?

Comment: It appears you're asking about TSA training which wouldn't be covered as part of aviation. You _might_ get help at [Travel.SE](http://travel.stackexchange.com), as they address a lot of TSA issues, but your best bet would be to contact the office where you submitted your request and ask them.

Comment: @FreeMan I believe he's submitted a request for TSA approval to start flight training under the [AFSP](https://www.flightschoolcandidates.gov/afsp2/?acct_type=c&section=WN) and he wants to extend the processing deadline. If so, it has nothing to do with air travel, although calling the AFSP helpline is probably still the best answer (this scenario isn't in their FAQ).

Comment: ah, I see, @Pondlife. Based on the previous VtC and the single `TSA` tag, I was attempting to be helpful. My misunderstanding.

Comment: @FreeMan No big deal :-) It made me think about a separate afsp tag, but we have very few TSA questions anyway so I don't think there's any big benefit to adding another tag right now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that you're in category 3 (aircraft under 12,500 lbs) then an approval is only valid for 365 days, so if you want to continue flight training after that then you need to request a new one:

> Once you have permission to train, you have 180 days to begin training
>   and 365 days to complete the approved training. Both of these time
>   periods start from the day you receive approval. For example, if you
>   begin flight training 30 days after you have been approved, you now
>   have 335 days to finish. If you do not finish, a new training request
>   must be submitted.

That's from the [AOPA AFSP guide](https://www.aopa.org/advocacy/pilots/alien-flight-training-program/aliens-and-non-us-citizens-seeking-flight-training); the TSA's [own AFSP webpage](https://www.flightschoolcandidates.gov/afsp2/?acct_type=c&section=WN) is a bit more difficult to use.